# How to set a table name using klepto sqltable_archive in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite, klepto

Based on the [klepto docs](https://klepto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/klepto.html#klepto.archives.sqltable_archive)

Using:

```
klepto.archives.sqltable_archive('sqlite:///foo.db', cached=False)
```

Successfully creates a database with the default table name of `memo`

However, when table is also included:

```
klepto.archives.sqltable_archive('sqlite:///foo.db', table='bar', cached=False)
```

The following error occurs:

```
  line 159, in __new__
    archive = _sqltable_archive(db, table, **kwds)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'table'
```

pointing to [line 159](https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/58012075d153c0135e18e8265ef33bd78c1a6ddb/klepto/archives.py#L159) in `klepto.archives`

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the `klepto` author.  Sorry the docs are not clear there.  If you look at the line above [(i.e. line 158)](https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/58012075d153c0135e18e8265ef33bd78c1a6ddb/klepto/archives.py#L158), you'll see that the table name is set with the keyword `name`... which then gets split into the `db` name and the `table` name.  I guess I could throw a better error when `table` is given as a keyword argument.

Comment: [this comment](https://github.com/uqfoundation/klepto/blob/58012075d153c0135e18e8265ef33bd78c1a6ddb/klepto/_archives.py#L1034) was easy to miss! Many thanks for the help.